# Taking backup of a Postgres table onto a different server

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

I have a prod postgres database on a server A, and I need to take backup of a specific table and store it directly onto a different server, server B (at a specific location).

The problem is I can't create a local dump file on server A, and transfer it to server B because the table size is quite large and there isn't enough space on A.

Is there any way to accomplish this using `pg_dump`?

Comment: You can pipe the output of `pg_dump` to a `psql` that connects to the target.

Comment: Something like this? `pg_dump -h host dbname -t tablename | psql -h target `